# How did zugzwang become an English word?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, german

The word *zugzwang* means a move in chess which forces your opponent to make a detrimental move; a move causing all of your opponent's options to be moves which will worsen their situation. Although it is definitely an English word, appearing in most English dictionaries, when I have tried to find out the [origin](https://www.etymonline.com/word/zugzwang) of the word the only information I have found is that it is a German word meaning "compulsion to move".

Does anyone know how this word entered the English vernacular?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a small amount of [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang#Etymology) would have provided the answer.

Comment: There are plenty of words 'borrowed' into one language from another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it entered the English language from publications on “chess game”  around the 1930s. From which its usage spread to to other game and sports.

> Usage notes: 
>   Zugzwang typically refers to a situation in which a player is forced to make a disadvantageous move though he or she would prefer not to make a move.

(Wiktionary )

> The earliest known use of the term zugzwang in English was on page 166 of the February 1905 issue of [Lasker's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Lasker) Chess Magazine.The term did not become common in English-language chess sources until the 1930s, after the publication of the English translation of Nimzowitsch's [My System](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_System) in 1929.

(Wikipedia)